# Html form and Django login system

Tags: python, html, django, forms

i want to make  simple login system with Django.I want to send a user to a page named 127.0.0.1:8000/login after submitting the form.From then i want to get the post data sent with the request, check if the users exist in the date base and return a html page if he logged in or anothet html page if the user  has not logged in.The problem is when i click the submit button of the form, it doesnt make request to /login.It stays at the same page.Any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body
<form action="/login/" method = "POST">
<input type="text" name="name"><br> 
 <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from simple import views as f
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^form/$', f.form), 
    url(r'^login/$', f.data)

]
```

Views.py

```
  from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from django.template import Context, loader

  def form(request):
     return render(request,"doccument.html")
  def data(request):
     name = request.POST.get('name')
     return HttpResponse(name)
```

Comment: What view do you have defined for the url `/login/`?

Comment: you can see the views, urls in the qeustion.I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your form `method` should be inside `quotes`,

```
<form action="/login/" method="POST">
```